# How to get a list of all extended properties for all objects

Tags: sql-server

I’ve been tasked with creating a query that will return following data:

[Schema Name], [Object Name], [Extended Property Name], [Extended Property Value]

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I’ve found fn_listextendedproperty function but that doesn’t help much.

Answer (score 37):

Use this query which is column specific:

```
SELECT S.name as [Schema Name], O.name AS [Object Name], ep.name, ep.value AS [Extended property]
FROM sys.extended_properties EP
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects O ON ep.major_id = O.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on O.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
```

Use this query for all extended properites:

```
SELECT S.name as [Schema Name], O.name AS [Object Name], ep.name, ep.value AS [Extended property]
FROM sys.extended_properties EP
LEFT JOIN sys.all_objects O ON ep.major_id = O.object_id 
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas S on O.schema_id = S.schema_id
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
```

Comment: Make those each left joins. Database extended properties will not match (null schema and object name), and inner joining on columns throws out all extended properties that aren't column specific.

Comment: This is great but probably want a c.name as [Column Name] in the selection for the column specific portion.

Answer (score 4):

This one brings all columns of an specific object, and its properties if they exists.

```
SELECT  
    O.name AS [Object Name],
    c.name, 
    ep.value AS [Extended property]
FROM 
    sys.columns AS c INNER JOIN 
    sys.all_objects O ON c.object_id = O.object_id LEFT JOIN 
    sys.extended_properties EP ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id   
WHERE
    O.name = 'table-name'
```